# CPUID SDK good alternatives

Tags: sdk

Hello I contacted CPUID support for CPUID SDK and they said 2500 USD, well thats quite a lot, is there cheaper or free alternatives to CPU-Z? Thank you

EDIT: Or can anyone give idea how CPU-Z works how do they access data that windows it self cannot see and where to begin?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late here, but you can find the full version of the SDK [here](https://github.com/onetom/guardian-server). (it's for C#.NET)

the git includes both the system information kit and the monitoring kit, good luck ;].